# C++ Calculator, Read Inputs with and without spaces

Tags: c++

I am writing a calculator program. When I run my code, if I enter `1 + 2` as the input, it will run as it should and print the output. However, if I enter `1+2` the program will not print out the output. I want to make it so that I can enter the inputs with or without the spaces. Some examples of inputs I want to be able to enter are `1     +2`, `1+     2`, and `1   +  2`. Could someone explain or demonstrate why it is that my code will not work with inputs like `1+2` but will with `1 + 2`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char op;
    double num1, num2;
    int sub1, sub2;
    std::string temp;

    while (true) {
        
        cin >> temp;
        
        if (temp.compare("exit") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else{
            num1 = std::stod(temp);
        }
        
        cin >> op >> num2;
        
        switch (op) {
        case '+':
            cout << num1 + num2 << endl;
            break;

        case '-':
            cout << num1 - num2 << endl;
            break;

        case '*':
            cout << num1 * num2 << endl;
            break;

        case '/':
            cout << num1 / num2 << endl;
            break;

        case '%':
            sub1 = num1;
            sub2 = num2;
            cout << sub1 % sub2 << endl;
            break;

        case '^':
            cout << pow(num1, num2) << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because cin considers space as delimiter for different inputs. cin will read the next item only if you have also given it another variable to store the read text.

Comment: @Sumit I am not sure I get what you mean. Could you refer me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the first cin on a string. When you input 1+2 into the console the entire '1+2' will be treated as a string and be inputted. When you input 1 + 2 the temp variable will only take '1' as it's input, string is space separated. A quick fix could be

changing your `std::string temp` to `char temp` and instead of

```
if (temp.compare("exit") == 0) {
    break;
}
```

try

```
if (temp == 'e') {
    break;
}
```

if you are forced to check your string then you could turn in into a string stream, assuming that the code is the same as given change the conditions. declare a string stream `stringstream os;` along with your other variables like `temp` etc... then change

```
else{
    num1 = std::stod(temp);
}
```

to

```
else{
    os << temp;
}
```

this will turn your string into a string stream I'd suggest you use getline() to take the entire input as one single string to cover both cases `1 + 2` and `1+2`

After that, you replace the `cin` with `os` this will effectively separate the data the  way you expected

Possible solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
char op ='a';
double num1, num2, num3 =0 ;
int sub1, sub2 = 0;
std::string temp;

int main() {



while (true) {

getline(cin, temp);

if (temp.compare("exit") == 0) {
break;
}

std::stringstream os (temp);
os >> num1 >> op >> num2 ;

switch (op) {
case '+':
cout << num1 + num2 << endl;
break;

case '-':
cout << num1 - num2 << endl;
break;

case '*':
cout << num1 * num2 << endl;
break;

case '/':
cout << num1 / num2 << endl;
break;

case '%':
sub1 = num1;
sub2 = num2;
cout << sub1 % sub2 << endl;
break;

case '^':
cout << pow(num1, num2) << endl;
break;
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aaah ok, I see. That could indeed work but there is something I did not metion. This is an assignment for a class so I have to use ``exit`` in order to exit the program. That is why I was sticking to ``std::string``. Is there a way to do it with ``std::string``?

Comment: Thanks, I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: By getting rid of ``num1 = std::stod(temp);`` then will temp stay as a string? I was thinking of using double type for the calculations. That's why I first started off as string and then converted to double.

Comment: I am also getting this error when I tried using ``std::stringstream os;``. ``error: aggregate ‘std::stringstream os’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   13 |  std::stringstream os;``

Comment: temp is always a string the `std::stod` does not change temp it copy it values process it and output a double temp will always be a string

Comment: you haven't include the library for it add `#include <sstream>`

Comment: I am trying to read ``temp`` with ``cin.getline(temp);`` and then ``op`` and ``num2`` with ``os`` like ``os << op << num2``. Is this correct? I am getting an error when I use ``getline`` like that.

Comment: typo, change `<<` to `>>`

Comment: Is your answer you wrote ``os << temp`` should that also be ``os>>temp``?

Comment: look at your original code it's `cin >> op >> num2;` you just change it to `<<` keep the direction symbol the same please

Comment: What about the implementation of ``cin.getline(temp);``, I am getting the following error: ``error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::string&)’
   19 |   cin.getline(temp);``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223392/discussion-between-chass-long-and-rivf).